# C# simpler way to find selected tab and do something with a control within it

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, tabcontrol

I am trying to find an easier way to implement this in my code. Not that I mind typing all of this but I am concerned with the amount of code I am going to have. My code sample here is just a small example of what I am trying to do. I will eventually when it is all said and done have 3 different buttons doing different actions for 50 different tabs.

I am new to C# so forgive my inexperience please and I am not looking for someone to code this for me if you can guide me in the right direction as to what type, function, method I need to use to do this efficiently would be greatly appreciated.

Anyway to the code. I am essentially making a customized web browser for my job that will have   50+ tabs for each tool I need to be able to access and I am simply making Back Button, Forward, Refresh etc but I need it to only do that function on the tab I currently have active.

```
private void backToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (frontierTabInner.SelectedTab == frontierTabInner.TabPages["inetTab"])
        {
            inetTabBrowser.GoBack();
            textBox1.Text = inetTabBrowser.Url.ToString();
        }
        if (frontierTabInner.SelectedTab == frontierTabInner.TabPages["frontierWikiTab"])
        {
            frontierWikiBrowser.GoBack();
            textBox1.Text = frontierWikiBrowser.Url.ToString();
        }
        if (frontierTabInner.SelectedTab == frontierTabInner.TabPages["loopcareTab"])
        {
            loopcareBrowser.GoBack();
            textBox1.Text = loopcareBrowser.Url.ToString();
        }
        if (frontierTabInner.SelectedTab == frontierTabInner.TabPages["vnetTab"])
        {
            vnetBrowser.GoBack();
            textBox1.Text = vnetBrowser.Url.ToString();
        }
        if (frontierTabInner.SelectedTab == frontierTabInner.TabPages["cdpiTab"])
        {
            cdpiBrowser.GoBack();
            textBox1.Text = cdpiBrowser.Url.ToString();

        }
        if (frontierTabInner.SelectedTab == frontierTabInner.TabPages["lolaTab"])
        {
            lolaBrowser.GoBack();
            textBox1.Text = lolaBrowser.Url.ToString();

        }
        if (frontierTabInner.SelectedTab == frontierTabInner.TabPages["billingLookupTab"])
        {
            billingLookupBrowser.GoBack();
            textBox1.Text = billingLookupBrowser.Url.ToString();
        }
```

I know there is an easier way to do this but I cannot seem to find it.

Any assistance would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `WebBrowser` control in the selected tab fairly easily:

```
private void backToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser wbControl =
       frontierTabInner.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<WebBrowser>().FirstOrDefault();
    wbControl.GoBack();
    textBox1.Text = wbControl.Url.ToString();
}
```

Assuming you only have one WebBrowser control in each tab. Otherwise you'd have to know either its name or index in order to find it.

Comment: Beautiful.. I knew there had to be an easier way then what I was doing and your solution works flawlessly and taught me a new concept I did not know existed lol. I should be able to implement this into the other buttons I need easily. Thanks!

Comment: Generics, lambda expressions and linq are three concepts that in my opinion every new C# programmer needs to learn. They make your life a lot simpler.